# How to present an AlertView from a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uialertview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a UICollectionView with a Map in the header.

I want to handle Core Location errors. I have 3 error types and for two of them I want to present a `UIAlertView`.

But I am getting an error, because `UICollectionViewCell` doesn't have a member called `presentViewController`.

```
func locationUnknown() {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Location Unknown", message: "Please try again later.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

    })
    alert.addAction(alertAction)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

How can I send this `UIAlertView` to the `UICollectionView`'s screen?

Comment: Get the parent `UICollectionView` and `presentViewController` there.

Comment: @ILikeTau `UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIView`, not of `UIViewController`. It doesn't know how to `presentViewController`.

Comment: do it in your viewcontroller in which you are using collectionview.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Oops. I mean the view controller.

Comment: How can i implement in the view controller?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the window's root view controller to present the alert:

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```