# Pop Alert if a CollectionViewCell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

There is a CollectionView with a couple items. I am trying to pop a alert message with textfield to create a new file when the item is selected.

However, when the last instruction (self.present(....)) is executed, an error message : "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" occurred.

I have also tried the code from 
 : [How to present an AlertView from a UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390726/how-to-present-an-alertview-from-a-uicollectionviewcell)
but it does not work as well.

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is it possible to do that? How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

```
func addFile(){    
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New file name:", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField{
        (textField: UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder=""
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    let createAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Create" ,style: .default){
        (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        let fileName = (alert.textFields?.first)! as UITextField
        print(fileName.text)
    }
    alert.addAction(createAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

EDIT: solved.

i modified the last line to 
`UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.present(alert,animated: true, completion: nil)`

and the alert box pop finally.

Comment: On which line you are getting the error specifically?

Comment: it stops at the "self.present(alert,animated:true,completion:nil)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use delegate. and I will demo some code to you.
first create prototype

```
protocol AlertViewDelegate {
      func alertSending(sender: UIAlertController)
}
```

than you implement in uicollectionviewcell class by

```
var delegate: AlertViewDelegate?
func actionMethod() { 
     let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New file name:", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
     alert.addTextField{
    (textField: UITextField!) -> Void in
     textField.placeholder=""
}
     let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",style: .cancel, handler: nil)
     alert.addAction(cancelAction)
     let createAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Create" ,style: .default){
    (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        let fileName = (alert.textFields?.first)! as UITextField
        print(fileName.text)
     }
     alert.addAction(createAction)
     delegate?.alertSending(sender: alert)
}
```

finally you go to your uicollectionviewcontroller class than extends delegate

```
extension ViewCollectionViewController: AlertViewDelegate {
func alertSending(sender: UIAlertController) {
    self.present(sender, animated: true, completion: nil)        
}
```

question please comment. hope it works for you. enjoy!

Comment: @chean enjoy! dear :)

Comment: ຄໍາຕອບທີ່ດີທີ່ສຸດຂອງປີ

Answer (score 0):

You have problems in these two lines:

```
let fileName = (alert.textFields?.first)! as UITextField
print(fileName.text)
```

Change them to these lines:

```
let fileName = alert.textFields?.first?.text
print(fileName!)
```

Comment: No. It's working fine. See [here](http://imgur.com/a/G6uUT). You might have some problems elsewhere

Comment: however, the alert is called by selecting a collection view cell, is it the same one as yours? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I've tried it with a project where I used `CollectionView` and it works just fine. [Here](http://imgur.com/a/r0QLn)

Comment: since the collectionview I am using is not created on the storyboard, it is just created by a class. I don't know if it matters.

Comment: Show the `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)` method's implementation

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let setting = settings[indexPath.item]
UIView.animate(withDuration:0.5){
   self.blackView.alpha = 0
   if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
    self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
   }
  }
    if setting.name == .addFile{
    ViewController().addFile()
}

Comment: Well. So where did you put your `UIAlertCotroller` showing code?

Comment: the func addFIle in the ViewController.swift

Comment: No. I just wanted to know ___where did you put the code that you added in your question___? Please edit your question with the enclosing block of that code.

Comment: I suspect that you have problem in `if setting.name == .addFile`. What's the data structure of your `setting` variable?

Comment: setting is a NSObject class with a string called name

Comment: So how are you comparing `setting.name` to `.addFile`? How even are you getting past this line without Xcode editor error?

Comment: as the name is an enumeration of string,
and addFile is one of the case,
so it can get past the editor

Comment: Well, I'm done. Can't help you with anything without having the source code.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share the whole source code. Anyway, thanks for all the help and sorry again if it wastes your time.

Answer (score 0):

Replace only the part with `createAction`

```
let createAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Create" ,style: .default){
     (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
     guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first,
         let fileName = textField.text else { return }
         print(fileName)
}
alert.addAction(createAction)
```